# How to highlight only the lines contain the 'MyString' in a RichEdit?

Tags: delphi, vcl, trichedit

I have created a small program the read a text file.

Once the text file is opened in a RichEdit, I want to change the background color of lines that contain a certain string, or to hide all lines that do not contain the string.
Is it possible?

I have tried to search for the string, but I haven't any idea of how to do what I'm asking for.

```
function SearchText(Control: TCustomEdit; Search: string; SearchOptions: TSearchOptions): Boolean;
var
  Text: string;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if soIgnoreCase in SearchOptions then
  begin
    Search := UpperCase(Search);
    Text := UpperCase(Control.Text);
  end
  else
    Text := Control.Text;

  Index := 0;
  if not (soFromStart in SearchOptions) then
    Index := PosEx(Search, Text, Control.SelStart + Control.SelLength + 1);
  if (Index = 0) and
      ((soFromStart in SearchOptions) or
       (soWrap in SearchOptions)) then
    Index := PosEx(Search, Text, 1);
  Result := Index > 0;
  if Result then
  begin
    Control.SelStart := Index - 1;
    Control.SelLength := Length(Search);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible, even very easy. What have you tried?

Comment: I have try to search, but i haven't how to do what i'm asking for.

Comment: This is kind of a poor SO question, because it is a bit like "please write the code for me". The natural approach would be to find the independent parts of the problem: (1) How to represent an array of strings (lines) in Delphi? (2) How to load a text file in Delphi into some in-memory array of strings? (3) How to search for a substring in a string in Delphi? (4) How to filter a Delphi in-memory array of strings? [This is trivial if you know 1 and has heard of loops. Doing it efficiently is slightly more interesting.] (5) How to populate a Delphi `TRichEdit` control? (6) How to set ...

Comment: ... background colour of a line in a `TRichEdit`. Indeed, if you know the answers to (1)--(6), doing what you want is trivial! I am sure you know most of these already, so which one in particular are you having issues with? Have you search Google or SO for that particular issue?

Comment: I might seem like a very grumpy old man now, but I think I do have a very important point about how to approach a programming problem.

Comment: I wrote the example, but I can't do what I asked for. If you have some example, shuold be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a poor SO question, because it is a bit like "please write the code for me".

The natural approach would be to find the independent parts of the problem:

1. How to represent an array of strings (lines) in Delphi?
2. How to load a text file in Delphi into some in-memory array of strings?
3. How to search for a substring in a string in Delphi?
4. How to filter a Delphi in-memory array of strings? [This is trivial if you know 1 and has heard of loops. Doing it efficiently is slightly more interesting.]
5. How to populate a Delphi `TRichEdit` control?

Indeed, if you know the answers to 1--5, doing what you want is trivial!

I might seem like a very grumpy old man now, but I think I do have a very important point about how to approach a programming problem.

Anyhow, let us address one issue at a time:

1. The old-school approach of a `array of string`, today written `TArray<string>` works. This is a dynamic array of strings. Since Delphi dynamic arrays are managed by the compiler, they are convenient because you don't need to create and free them manually. However, they are a bit low-level and are sometimes misused.

   Probably a better alternative for you is to use the `TStringList` class.
2. In `IOUtils`, you find `TFile.ReadAllLines` which takes a file name and returns the contents of the (text) file as an array of strings.

   Or use `TStringList.LoadFromFile` if you have a `TStringList`.
3. Traditionally, you would use the `Pos` function. But today you can use the `string` helper: `MyString.Contains()`. Obviously, you need to decide if you want to treat CAPITALS and small letters as identical or not.
4. Use a trivial `for` or `for in` loop to populate a second array from the original array, based on the test from 3.
5. If you have a `TStringList`, just use `TRichEdit.Lines.Assign`.

Putting it all together, using a fairly smart combination of `string` arrays and `TStringList`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var Lines := TFile.ReadAllLines('K:\test.txt');

  var FilteredLines := TStringList.Create;
  try

    for var Line in Lines do
      if Line.Contains('MyString') then
        FilteredLines.Add(Line);

    RichEdit1.Lines.Assign(FilteredLines);

  finally
    FilteredLines.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Of course, there are a thousand variations on this theme.

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine, it's showing only the lines contains my string.
Another question:
you code Var Lines := TFile.ReadAllLines('C:\myfile.txt');
read the file from location, in case i have already opened the file in my TRichedit?
Thank you.

Comment: @SHKODRAN: Yes, certainly. I think you can figure out how to do that.

Comment: Either you make a very small change to the code above, or you can do simply `for var i := RichEdit1.Lines.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    if not RichEdit1.Lines[i].Contains('MyString') then
      RichEdit1.Lines.Delete(i);`. Yes, that's a three-liner!

Answer (score 1):

Searching and filtering text *before* putting it into the RichEdit is best.

However, if the text is already loaded in the RichEdit, `TRichEdit` does have a [`FindText()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.FindText) method you can use, you should not be searching its `Text` property manually.  For example:

```pascal
function SearchText(Control: TCustomRichEdit; const Search: string; SearchOptions: TSearchOptions): Boolean;
var
  StartPos, SearchLen, Index: Integer;
  Options: TSearchTypes;
begin
  if soIgnoreCase in SearchOptions then
    Options := []
  else
    Options := [stMatchCase];

  if soFromStart in SearchOptions then
  begin
    StartPos := 0;
    SearchLen := Control.GetTextLen;
    Index := Control.FindText(Search, StartPos, SearchLen, Options);
  end else
  begin
    StartPos := Control.SelStart + Control.SelLength;
    SearchLen := Control.GetTextLen - StartPos;
    Index := Control.FindText(Search, StartPos, SearchLen, Options);
    if (Index = -1) and (soWrap in SearchOptions) then
      Index := Control.FindText(Search, 0, StartPos, Options);
  end;
  Result := Index <> -1;
  if Result then
  begin
    Control.SelStart := Index;
    Control.SelLength := Length(Search);
  end;
end;
```

That being said, setting the background color of a line, or removing a line (there is no option to "hide" a line), is fairly simple.

Given any character index, you can send the RichEdit an [`EM_LINEFROMCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-linefromchar) message to determine the line index that the character appears on.

You can then remove the line from the RichEdit by using the `TRichEdit.Lines.Delete()` method.

To set the line's background color takes a few steps:

- send the RichEdit [`EM_LINEINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-lineindex) and [`EM_LINELENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-linelength) messages to determine the line's starting and ending character indexes.
- set the RichEdit's `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties (or send the RichEdit an [`EM_EXSETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-exsetsel) message).
- send the RichEdit an [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcharformat) message, specifying the SCF_SELECTION flag and using the [`CHARFORMAT2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-charformat2w) record, to set the background color of the selection.